# Creating SUMIFS formula to get sum of Col"B"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck on a formula to SUM the `Col"B"` values between 2 dates by matching the `Col"A"` but formula is not giving an answer.

any help will be appreciated.

my formula

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A15,F2,B2:B15,C2:C15,">="&F1,C2:C15,"<="&G1)
```

[image]

Comment: Your picture is Google Sheets, but you tagged Excel.  Should this be tagged google sheets?  They are different apps.

Comment: I have been using Excel Sheets but make that example on google sheets. I need an answer for MS Excel

Comment: Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF and SUMIFS have different ordering.  The sum column in SUMIFS is the first criterion not the third like it is in SUMIF:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B15,A2:A15,F2,C2:C15,">="&F1,C2:C15,"<="&G1)
```

Comment: Yeah i got that. Both SUMIF and SUMIFS has been developed by separate developer maybe :P Thats why the order is change

Comment: SUMIF came first, then later they added SUMIFS, which required a change to the order to make work.  It has to do with how param arrays work.

Comment: It is also why I only use SUMIFS, then I do not need to remember.